# Error playing .wav files in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, mp3, wav

I tried playing .wav files in VS2008 ,using the following command:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

PlaySound((LPCWSTR)"snd1.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC);
```

But all I hear is the Windows 'Beep' Sound !

I couldn't figure out whats causing this problem. Any help in this direction would be nice!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't just cast a narrow character string to a wide character pointer and expect it to work.  Pass an actual wide character string.

```
PlaySound(L"snd1.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the OS that you want to play file.

```
PlaySound((LPCWSTR)L"snd1.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME);
```

Comment: You don't _need_ to; [it'll be deduced as long as there's no matching win.ini entry or registry association](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal But if you do specify SND_FILENAME, the OS won't have to try to figure out what you want.